# Apostrophe Widgets not saving

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Guys when I fill all the widget data and I click save it doesn't seem to work every time. Let's say it works 7/10 times. (By working I mean I can see the widget is rendered properly. ie Html is produced ). So I opened the network tab and I found this. Whenever I fill the fields and click save there is a post call to **/modules/apostrophe-areas/render-widget** and when I dig into its response I'm able to see the **html** with all the **data that I filled** and it returns a **200 status code**. But when the page renders all the widget data is lost and it shows an empty widget.

This doesn't occur all the time but I have to look into this as the widgets we fill are time-consuming. Let me know if this is a known bug or something.

Comment: Hi bharath, this is not a known bug, no - not working only 70% of the time... anything in the node.js console window when this happens? Anything in the browser console window from javascript when this happens?

render-widget doesn't do the actual saving. That would be a separate request.

Is this widget being edited in context on the page? As part of a pieces editor modal? Somewhere else?

Comment: Hey tom. The widget is edited using the form that appears when you click on the widget. So when I actually click save there was no error on my server console as well as my browser console. The render-widget seems to produce the correct html ( Data I filled in the widget ) is there which means the fetch from mongo db is happening properly. Its somewhere in the rendering phase that something is going wrong.

Comment: render-widget is just based on what you posted back to the server and nothing has been saved to the database yet at that point. If you hit refresh and it's gone, then it was never in the database.

Comment: What we'll need to help is steps to reproduce this. Preferably with a fork of github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-sandbox that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks tom. Will get back to you.